# Change colour of button highlighted when using tab button

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I'm currently trying to make my application more keyboard/visually friendly for a user. I added a few features that will provide a better visual indication for the user but I noticed when using the buttons it's difficult to see when the button is currently highlighted when tabbing down the application.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xH1w9.png)

As shown in the example, we can see that the button on the left is highlighted. However I would like it so either the highlight feature is a different cover or is bigger so the user can see that is the case.

```
 <button class="btn btn-blue" ng-click="handleCreate()" ng-show="isNew" ng-disabled="detailsForm.$invalid">
        Create
 </button>
```

I would assume I need to modify the css, but I'm not too sure how to achieve that or what tags I would need. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

For that there is `:focus` selector. ([Read more](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_focus.asp))

```css
button:focus {
  background: #ff0000;
}
```

```html
<button>TEST1</button>
<button>TEST2</button>
<button>TEST3</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `:focus` rule.

For example:

```
.button:focus {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```